# process is not defined in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, process, environment-variables

I tried to use the `process.env.process.env.VUE_APP_SERVER_URL` in my vue project. But I got the error like the following.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

It's using the webpack and run by `npm start` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code in `webpack.config.js`.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/.env' })

module.exports = {
   ...
   plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env': JSON.stringify(dotenv.parsed),
      }),
   ]
   ...
}
```